# Can not get CORS to work with restify, all preflight OPTIONS return with 405

Tags: node.js, cors, restify

I've read MANY articles at this point and tried just about every configuration I can think of to make CORS work with restify.  I've used `restify.CORS()` with `restify.fullResponse()` and every other combination. I've also tried just using the cors lib (npm install cors) to no avail.  My app looks like:

```
/**
 * Setup middlewares.
 */
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());
server.use(restify.cors());
server.use(restify.fullResponse());
server.use(morgan('dev'));
```

I've also tried adding opts handling with:

```
server.opts('/\.*/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE');
  res.send(204);
  return next();
});
```

In every case, I get back:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/1.0.0/clients. Response to preflight 
request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is 
present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://run.plnkr.co' is therefore not 
allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

Any ideas?  This is with restify 4.0.3.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in module for CORS:

```
server.use(restify.CORS({
  origins: ['*'],
  credentials: false, // defaults to false
  headers: ['']  // sets expose-headers
}));
```

Your solution should work as well if you actually add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header ;-)

Comment: TypeError: restify.CORS is not a function

Comment: It's been deprecated: https://github.com/TabDigital/restify-cors-middleware

Answer (score 0):

Use server.opts method to wirte your own handler for OPTIONS request. Below is the example you can use.

Also tell me if you are using set-credentials flag to true while making request from the browser. This handle in that case would have to respond with access cookies.

In the example below, I am returning the allowed origin for exact match. You can tweak it to be substring match also. But always return the exact value as found in request header origin in the response header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. Its a good practice.

```
server.opts('/\.*/', (req, res) => {
const origin = req.header('origin');
const allowedOrigins = ['example.com', 'example.org'];
if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1) {
    //origin is not allowed
    return res.send(405);
}
//set access control headers to allow the preflight/options request
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', header);
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS');

// Access-Control-Max-Age header catches the preflight request in the browser for the desired
// time. 864000 is ten days in number of seconds. Also during development you may want to keep
// this number too low e.g. 1.
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', 864000);
return res.send(200);
```